# Excel: lookup the last non-zero, non-empty cell in filtered range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

The following formula gives the last visible data in a filtered range:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(R5,ROW(R5:R200)-ROW(R5),0)),R5:R200)
```

However, it'd return zero if the last visible cell contains zero. Anyway to filter off zero and return the last greater than zero cell?

The following is a simplified example. Both date and sport are filtered. The filters could be altered so June and basket ball are displayed, for example.

The next two columns are the balance of two currencies. I need a formula at the bottom of the currencies that displays 193 and 525 respectively.  The lookup formula I found on the net displays 193 and 0, where 0 is the last number in the filtered data of a currency. What I want to display is 525, not 0. By the way, zero is not zero per se. Zero means no transaction. It actually should be blank. However, I can't make them blank because they are involved in calculation. Addition of a number to a blank gives an error.

This is for a monthly balance sheet report. I need to report 193 and 525 as the ending balances for July.

```
2019/07/01  tennis  775           0
2019/07/11  tennis  925           0
2019/07/11  tennis  0           125
2019/07/13  tennis  0           105
2019/07/13  tennis  0           525
2019/07/25  tennis  193           0
```

Another formula:

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(R5:R200<>0),R5:R200)
```

will display the last non-zero number, whether visible or not. It's not what I want either.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output? You might not have to filter your range first. For example `MAX` or `LARGE` and `AGGREGATE` can be used in formulas to retrieve the last non value higher than 0 for specific criteria in other columns.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an example. Hope that'll clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me is this one:

```
LOOKUP(2,1/INDEX(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(R5,ROW(R5:R200)-ROW(R5),0))*R5:R200,0),ROW(R5:R200))
```

It returns the row number of the last non-empty cell in a filtered range.

This is how it works:

The SUBTOTAL function returns an array of 0 and 1, 0 for invisible cells, 1 for visible. R5:R200 is an array of the values in R5:R200. When these two are multiplied, 0 in R5:R200 multiplies 1 or 0 in SUBTOTAL to give 0. The resulting array elements are 0 if a) the cells are invisible (filtered off) or b) the cell content is 0. So, the resulting array contains a bunch of 0 except those cells who are visible and whose value is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

One was of accomplish this is adding your formula above into an index match formula. It would look something like this

=INDEX(R5:R200,(LOOKUP(2,1/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(R5,ROW(R5:R200)-ROW(R5),0)),R5:R200),1)

I use a similar formula; 
INDEX(Entry20!D2:D367,(LOOKUP(2,1/(Entry20!BG2:BG367<>0),ROW(Entry20!BG2:BG367))),1)
in my case column D contains the date and I'm looking for the date that the last non-zero value came up. I tried changing this to BG2:BG367 and it provided the last non-zero value.

I hope this helps,
Brad

Comment: The formula gives #VALUE!.

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work for you. I looked at it again and what I'm using and it works for me.

Comment: Actually, when I copied and pasted the formula to my spreadsheet, Excel said there was an error in the formula. I checked the formula and found the number of opening and closing parentheses did not match. So, I removed the opening parenthesis in front of LOOKUP, which resulted in #VALUE!.