# Excel array operation: how to get this array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have the following two arrays:

```
 {a,b,c}

 {d,e,f}
```

How do I get this array?

```
 {a*d,b*e,c*f}
```

For example, one array is {0,1,1}, another is {255,122,0}. I need this array:

```
{0,122,0}
```

It is really just this simple.

This is related to this thread:[Excel: lookup the last non-zero, non-empty cell in filtered range](https://superuser.com/questions/1475810/excel-lookup-the-last-non-zero-non-empty-cell-in-filtered-range/1475855#1475855)

I have found that this formula SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(R5,ROW(R5:R200)-ROW(R5),0)) gives 1 for the filtered data (visible) and 0 for those filtered off (invisible). So, this is an array with 196 elements of 0 or 1.

Another array, OFFSET(R5,ROW(R5:R200)-ROW(R5),0), basically, is just R5:R200.

If I can multiple each element of one array by its corresponding counterpart in another array and get a new array, then, the following LOOKUP will give the last non-zero number in the filtered data.

=LOOKUP(2,1/NEW-ARRAY,R5:R200)

This is because the SUBTOTAL array gives 1 for each filtered (visible) cell and when it is multiplied with the cell content, those visible cells with content of 0 will become 0 in the new array (the second 1 in {0,1,1} times 0 in {255,122,0}). So, the last non-zero cell will be picked up by LOOKUP.

Comment: maybe `SUMPRODUCT({a,b,c}, {d,e,f})` ...? There are elements allowed in SUMPRODUCT and elements that are not allowed so it's anyone's guess that this will work better than a strict array formula.

Comment: I think SUMPRODUCT gives the sum, not an array. I need the array because I need it for further operation.

Comment: If you need an array returned as the result then use INDEX in its array form.

Comment: I think INDEX only returns one element in the array, not the entire array. I need the entire array. I have edited the question and give an example.

Comment: ... and that is as good as I can provide in comments withour sample data and expected results.

Comment: Please include a sample with actual data that one can multiply and expected output.

Comment: *I have one function that generates one array and another function that generates a second array. I need the two arrays to give the desired array* Write third function...

Comment: @joehua,,, my simple suggestion is,, [Edit] your post and and sample data along with expected output,, in fact your lookup formula achieves nothing !!

Comment: OK. I have edited the question again. I think this is the best I can do. But I can't figure out why getting {a * d,b * e,c * f} from {a,b,c} and {d,e,f} would not get the point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jeeped stated use INDEX:

```
INDEX({0,1,1}*{255,122,0},0)
```

This will return the array {0,122,0} to another formula

As you can see if we sum the numbers:

```
=SUM(INDEX({0,1,1}*{255,122,0},0))
```

Which returns 122

Answer (score 0):

*This formula can get elements of an array in desire form:*

[image]

- Enter this formula in Cell `A44` & fill right till required.

`=A42*D42`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have in cells A1, B1 and C1 you have 1, 2, and 3 respectively.
And in cells A2, B3 and C2 you have 4, 5, and 6 respectively.

In cell A3, you can enter the formula:

= A1:C1 * A2:C2

and it will generate an array of {4,10,18} that will spill into A3, B3 and C3 respectively.